# Is it possible to convert a database from Approach to Access, SQL Server or Oracle / other?

Tags: .net, sql, oracle, ms-access

Here is my situation:

I have an old Database that works fine, It was created many years ago in "Smartsuite Approach", I was wondering, Is it possible to convert the database (the backend and the frontend) to a newer database solution approach like: From SmartSuite Approach to Microsoft Access, SQL Server, Oracle or other ect..

I have done some research which has identified that ONLY the "backend" not the "frontend" can be succesfully converted into Access by saving the Approach database to a .dbf file and then opening the .dbf file in Access.. This works for the backend (which then cannot be modified but thats ok..) but my question now is can the frontend also be converted in any other database solution? i.e. SQL Server, Oracle.. or other ect.?.

I need the frontend (views and functionality) to also be converted as the client doesn't want a new solution just a quick conversion of the old solution so that they can run their database in a product that is supported in recent operating systems like windows 7 in either Access, SQL Server, Oracle or another supported database approach.

Any help / advice would be appreciated.

Comment: @Remou: I assumed the question is about Lotus SmartSuite Approach: that is, the database application in the Lotus Smartsuite office suite called 'Approach' (bBASE). Your comment is like responding, "What about Microsoft Office?" when someone is asking to convert Microsoft Access to .NET. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Lotus SmartSuite was an office suite, intended to be a Microsoft Office 'killer app' and dates from the era of proprietary file formats. I actually liked it a lot: its UI was far superior to MS Office at the time. Access dialogs with bound controls work in a fundamentally different way (more like reports, really) to other Windows forms apps, including Approach. So I wouldn't hold out too much hope of finding a conversion tool.

Answer (score 0):

I'm familiar with Oracle. I'm not entirely sure on your definition of backend and frontend. I am under the impression that when you say backend you are talking about data tables and front end you are talking about views on those table.

This should help you converting to Oracle (might need tweeking for later versions of oracle, but the concept will be the same):

[http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:711825134415](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:711825134415)

Answer (score 0):

I highly doubt you can simply convert your database.

However if you can get the data into CSV or some other common format it shouldn't be too hard to get the data into Oracle, SQL sever etc.  If you do use Oracle it may be worth looking at Apex (Application Express)as a rapid development framework which may be able to quickly and easily provide you with an interface for the data.  It might be worth checking if any of your oracle guys have experience with Apex.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/learnmore/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I have found that it is not possible to convert a SmartSuite database to an SQL Database or Oracle database because the way the relationships are worked out in the programs are very different. There are no conversion tools that i have been able to find. Therefore the solution is to export the data to a .csv file as suggested by Emu and Re-Create the database structure in Oracle or SQL Server and then import the data into the new Database and Front-End you created.